# Python converts long number to float I believe ( example: x.xxxe+yy)

Tags: python

I'm doing a little script with python and twitter, and it's working fine and everything, except for one little thing.

When I'm importing the id of the tweets of a certain user, I print them out to see if I'm getting correct information, and I am, when I print it out it comes as something like this:

```
330090997180665856
```

(some random tweet from cnn.) However, I'm using texttable to print them into a table next to the retweet count of each of the tweets I'm getting, and that's working fine as well. However in the column where the tweet id goes it shoes this:

```
3.301e+17
```

I'm assuming this is because python recognized this as a long and made it into a float for some reason. I transform it into a string, or an int right before I append it to the list of tweets, but the problem is still there, and I don't know what to do, I've tried doing long(tweet_id) but that doesn't work either.

There might be some ridiculously easy solution but I havent found any :/

EDIT: This is what my code looks like:
some OAuth before but didn't put it here

```
def main():
USER_ID = raw_input("Enter User Id: ")
COUNT = input("How many tweets to analyze: ")
OUT_FILE_NAME = OUT_DIR + 'output_file_test' + USER_ID + '.txt'

tweet_list = []
retweet_count_list = []
total_retweets = 0
#tweet_cursors = Cursor(api.user_timeline, id = USER_ID).items(COUNT)
while True:
    try:
        for tweet_cursor in Cursor(api.user_timeline, id = USER_ID).items(COUNT):
            print "cursoring"
            x = str(tweet_cursor.id)
            tweet_list.append(x)
            print x
            y = tweet_cursor.retweet_count
            retweet_count_list.append(y)
            print y
            total_retweets = total_retweets + y

        break
    except TweepError, e:
        some error handling


avg_retweet = total_retweets / COUNT
print "The Average retweets per tweet was: "
print avg_retweet
header = ["Tweet Id", "Retweet Amount"]
tab.header(header)
tab.set_cols_width([30,30])
for i in range(0, COUNT):
    one = str(tweet_list[i])
    two = str(retweet_count_list[i])
    tab.add_row([one, two])
output_table = tab.draw()
print output_table
```

Comment: Share the script code with us, then we can help.

Comment: Python does not by itself change long int values to float. Please share some of the code handling the tweets (including where you add it to the table) so we can see where things go wrong.

Comment: I don't know the solution but I know what's _not_ causing this: _Python_. Must be the `texttable` thingy or something.

Comment: Python does not change longs to floats by itself, The problem seems to be in your handling of the tweet data.. and so it's definitely **not** caused by Python, but by somewhere in the code..

Comment: Probably the problem is in texttable module. Try to convert your integers to strings when you pass them to texttable.

Comment: I see, I put the code there, but let me try changing it when going to texttable

Comment: The thing is I do make them strings before texttable, could it be that python does it when I append them to the list?

Comment: When you print x after appending to list, does it display correctly (it should, but it may be messed up already which would pinpoint the problem)?

Comment: yeah it comes out correctly, and that's why I can't figure out where the mistake is. It comes out as "330117735956750336" for example

Comment: Then just go forward and check it before and after tab_draw and so on till you find the faulty function (my guess is on add_row).

Comment: when I print one and two it prents them like this
330325785615405057 29
which is correct (tweet_id retweet_count)
so the problem must have something to do with texttable, maybe the library converts them into floats automatically?

Comment: Well you are using open library so feel free to delve into the function that "ruins it" and find out why it converts it :).

Comment: There are no floats here. This way of displaying numbers is called [Scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Comment: Never mind, texttable has automatic formatting for the entered data, but you can choose as well, so should I make my data appear as an integer? Thanks for your time everyone.
http://foutaise.org/code/texttable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `set_cols_dtype` to an integer (`'i'`).  Looks like it defaults to auto (`'a'`).

```
table = texttable.Texttable()
table.set_cols_dtype(['i',   # integer
                      'a' ]) # automatic
table.add_rows([['int', 'auto'], [330090997180665856, 330090997180665856], [1, 1]])
print table.draw()
```

Gives:

```
+--------------------+-----------+
|        int         |   auto    |
+====================+===========+
| 330090997180665856 | 3.301e+17 |
+--------------------+-----------+
| 1                  | 1         |
+--------------------+-----------+
```